# Почему заблокирован буфер обмена?

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

Я хочу скопировать текст с помощью модуля `pyperclip`

Вот, что я написал:

```
def CopyText():
    pyperclip.copy("Hello, world!")
```

и когда я вызываю функцию у меня выскакивает данная ошибка:
`pyperclip.PyperclipWindowsException: Error calling OpenClipboard ([WinError 5] Отказано в доступе.)`

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Если это на linux, то нужен xclip.

Comment: @СергейКох, я изменил вопрос к минимальному примеру

Comment: @Delvin у меня windows

Comment: А если запустить от администратора?

Comment: @gil9red я не умею скрипт запускать от имени адмистратора

Comment: @DMITRY1234455
в проводнике ПКМ, свойства, галочку на "запускать от имени адмистратора"

Comment: Если буфер вообще у вас работает, то дело, вероятно, не в модуле, а в python. Он сам случаем не от админа установлен?

Comment: @Delvin я не совсем понял вопрос про админа, знаю только, что у меня есть проекты где pyperclip работает, скрипт для копирования одинаковый и там и там. Почему тут не работает я понятия не имею

Comment: @DMITRY1234455
Эммм... А Вы это в IDE запускаете? А перед запуском сохранили файл?
В консоли все прекрасно работает.
https://i.imgur.com/rjmQVw0.png

Comment: @Delvin файл сохранён, запускаю через командную строку. У меня не работает(ошибка та же)

Comment: @DMITRY1234455 Судя по всему, это проблема винды выше в.8
https://www.google.ru/search?q=Error+calling+OpenClipboard+([WinError+5]++access+denided

Попробуйте что-то вроде:
while True:

 try:

  return pyperclip.copy("Hello, world!")

 except pywintypes.error as e:

  if e.winerror!=5 or retries==0:

   time.sleep(delay)

   return pyperclip.copy("Hello, world!")

Comment: Проблема не новая: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues/119

Comment: @Delvin Я только что сделал новый файл и написал туда `pyperclip.copy("Hello, world")`, и оно сработало. Ошибка срабатывает только на том файле где я пишу основной проект в функции, я только что сделал `pyperclip.copy("Hello, world")` в самом начале программы и оно работает, ошибка происходит только тогда-когда я делаю эту команду в функции

Comment: @DMITRY1234455
а с пробелами у вас нормально?

Comment: @Delvin я провел небольшой тест и понял, что ошибка срабатывает тогда когда я делаю команду `pyperclip.copy("Hello, world")` в функции которая привязана к виджету Menu в модуле tkinter